# Why EF Core not set Custom Annotation?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In DbContext i declare model as below:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<FileStore>().Property(x => x.FileStoreId)
            .ValueGeneratedNever()
            .ForSqlServerHasDefaultValueSql("NewSequentialId()")
            .HasAnnotation("RowGuidColumn", true);
```

but after add migration, HasAnnotation("RowGuidColumn", true) not add any Annotation to Column:

```
 columns: table => new
            {
                FileStoreId = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "NewSequentialId()"),
                CreationTime = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(nullable: false),
            }
```

and i most add Annotation directly:

```
FileStoreId = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "NewSequentialId()").**Annotation("RowGuidColumn", true)**
```

how i can add Annotation that Generate auto in Add-Migration?

Comment: Is RowGuidCol supported by EF migrations at all? AFAIK you have to add it to your migrations code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The provider specifies which model annotations are copied/transformed into the migration operations. To do what you're asking, you'd need to override the provider-specific `IMigrationsAnnotationProvider` service.

```
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString)
  .ReplaceService<SqlServerMigrationsAnnotationProvider, MyMigrationsAnnotationProvider>();
```

And here's the implementation.

```
class MyMigrationsAnnotationProvider : SqlServerMigrationsAnnotationProvider
{
    public override IEnumerable<IAnnotation> For(IProperty property)
        => base.For(property)
            .Concat(property.GetAnnotations().Where(a => a.Name == "RowGuidColumn"));
}
```

From there you'd need to do something to turn it into SQL by overriding the provider-specific `IMigrationsSqlGenerator` service.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I forget to change AnnotationProvider.