# Column Order EF Core Net 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I am working with entity framework and NET5, and I am trying to set the column order value in the definition, but when creating the migration and updating the database, the table does not reflect the order that I set.
Here the code:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ApplicationUser> builder)
    {
        //builder.Ignore(e => e.DomainEvents);
        builder.ToTable("uauser", "sec");
        builder.HasKey(p => p.Id).HasName("pk_uapuser");
        builder.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("uaid").HasAnnotation("Order", 1).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(t => t.CompanyId).HasColumnName("uacompanyid").HasAnnotation("Order", 2).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(t => t.PersonalId).HasColumnName("uapid").HasAnnotation("Order", 3).HasMaxLength(30).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("uaname").HasAnnotation("Order", 4).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();
    }
```

Thank you very much for the help!!!.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why EF Core not set Custom Annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42459957/why-ef-core-not-set-custom-annotation)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42459957/why-ef-core-not-set-custom-annotation

Comment: See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41266992/entityframework-code-first-set-order-of-fields).